# Асинхронность js (подвисание скрипта)

Tags: javascript, async-await, асинхронность

Подскажите пожалуйста, как предотвратить временного зависания скрипта во время работы цикла.
Насколько я знаю, нельзя параллельно работать с DOM, тогда возник вопрос, а как тогда? Пока функция `build(full)` занята своими делами, хочется заняться ещё чем нибудь полезным.

```js
function go(){
  containerHTML = document.querySelector(".container").style.display = "none";
  t0 = performance.now();
  for (let i=0; i<1000; i++){}
  t1 = performance.now();
  let i = 0;
  let goTimer;
  goTimer = setInterval(()=>{timevis.innerText = i; i++; if(i>100)clearTimeout(goTimer);},(t1-t0)*1500)
  build();
}
async function build(){
  pixel = +pixel.value;
  canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for(let i=0;i<window.innerWidth;i+=pixel)
    for(let j=0;j<window.innerHeight;j+=pixel){
      canvas.fillStyle = `rgb(${Math.random()*256},${Math.random()*256},${Math.random()*256})`;
      canvas.fillRect(i, j, pixel, pixel);
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
<div class="container">
      <h4>Введите сторону квадратов</h4>
      <input type="number" id="pixel" min="1" value="1"><b>px</b><br>
      <button onclick="go()">Отрисовать все сразу</button>
</div>
<h1 id="timevis"></h1>
```

Comment: "вопрос, а как тогда?" - последовательно. Иначе не получится, т.к. JS выполняется однопоточно. Асинхронность тоже однопоточная, коллбэки в асинхр. очереди выполняются поочередно.

Comment: Можно разве что размазать вычисления одной задачи по нескольким итерациям цикла событий - это конечно не позволит одновременно выполнять несколько задач (и общее время выполнения размазанной задачи увеличится), но некоторые другие задачи (включая перерисовку страницы браузером) могут быть выполнены раньше.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017660/html5-canvas-better-pixel-control-and-better-speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вместо цикла использовать таймер и вызывать функцию повторно. И за раз отрисовывать какое-то количество блоков, тогда можно убрать подвисание, например:

```js
function go(){
  containerHTML = document.querySelector(".container").style.display = "none";
  let i = 0;
  let goTimer = setInterval(()=>{timevis.innerText = i; i++; if(i>100)clearTimeout(goTimer);},20)
  let canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  build();
}
function build(count = 1000, i = 0, j = 0, pix = +pixel.value, canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas").getContext('2d')){ //count - здесь типо количество отрисовываемых блоков за раз
  for (let k=0; k<count; k++){
    canvas.fillStyle = `rgb(${Math.random()*256},${Math.random()*256},${Math.random()*256})`;
    canvas.fillRect(i, j, pix, pix);
    if (j<window.innerHeight) j+=pix; else {j=0; i+=pix;}
    if (i<window.innerWidth) ; else return;
  }
  setTimeout(build, 2, count, i, j, pix, canvas); //запускаем еще раз
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mainCanvas"></canvas>
<div class="container">
      <h4>Введите сторону квадратов</h4>
      <input type="number" id="pixel" min="1" value="1"><b>px</b><br>
      <button onclick="go()">Отрисовать все сразу</button>
</div>
<h1 id="timevis"></h1>
```